# Zabbix trigger does not resolve for CentOS 7

Tags: linux, triggers, centos, zabbix, agent

I have zabbix version 3.4. i have 2 templates. one for monitoring the OS and the other for monitoring Databases. i have few servers with CentOS 6.9  added to these templates. everything works just fine.

then i added 4 servers to these templates with CentOS 7. items works correctly. they have the expected results. the problem is when a trigger is activated for these 4 servers, they don't resolve and stay active and we see them in dashboard.

for example, in Database template, we have an item that is for service status. if it is `1` then it means service is running, if it is something other than `1` it means service is not running. i stopped the service on one of those CentOS 7 servers. the result that agent got was 0. trigger was activated. then i started the service. in latest data i can see that the value is `1` which means service is running, but the trigger did't resolved and it is still up.

then i did the above steps for one of the CentOS 6.9 servers and everything works just fine.

why this happens and how i can fix it?

Update:
the trigger expression is:

```
   {log-b:db2stat.db2instance_service[].last()}<>1
```

Comment: could you share your trigger expression as well ?

Comment: also, you should consider upgrading to Zabbix 5

Comment: @IronBishop service is not for our team. we only use it. i should tell the other team see what they can do.

Comment: the trigger is straightforward, reacts on the .last(). I agree with @IronBishop, you should ask the service owner to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: Upgrading to zabbix 5 on CentOS 7 with puppet will be a challenge in view of PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: maybe check the DB logs if some inserts/updates are not failing (especially in event_recovery and problem tables)

Short story long:
We observe the similar behaviour on ZBX 4.4 and only with certain triggers checking last 10 minutes of data (e.g. item_key.str('problem',10m)=1 ). The problem get detected but later will not get resolved even after several days event though the trigger conditions are no longer matched.

In our particular case:

- I looked into DB and found the event with appropriate eventid (e.g. 123) in events table and noted down objectid (e.g.100123)
- Then I checked the events table for the specific objectid (100123) and found that indeed there was a "resolution" event (e.g. 125)
- when checked event_recovery table I couldn't find an entry which would match those two eventids (while in case of other triggers, they had an entry in event_recovery table after they got resolved)
- I simply created the entry: insert into event_recovery (eventid, r_eventid) VALUES ('123', '125');
- it is not enough however as the similar pairing needs to be adjusted in problems table
- in problems table I found a problem with my eventid (123) and simply mapped recovery event to that: update problem set r_eventid='125' where eventid='123' and objectid='100123';

  The problem with this is that this is not a solution, just a one time workaround. The issue keeps popping up and at this time we suspect the problem is on database side (we have a primary+standby DB with selects directed to standby which can cause certain select operations which do write in the end to fail as standby DB is in read-only mode).

  We will try to redirect everything to primary DB to see if it helps.